# Split input string and form comma separated outputs

Tags: c#, linq

We have an input string with several dots separated values and each of these units is separated by space.
If the input is like:

string input = "1.2 3.4 5.6 7.8 9", we need to break it as:

string beforeDots="1,3,5,7,9"         // all ints before the dot.

string afterDots="2,4,6,8"         // all ints after the dot.

We have tried this by:

```
string inputSplit=input.Split(' ');
string beforeDots=string.Empty;
string afterDots=string.Empty;
foreach (string input in inputSplit)
{
   if (input.IndexOf(".") > 0)
      afterDots += "," + s.Split('.')[1];
   else
      beforeDots += "," + s;
}

if(afterDots.Length > 0)
   afterDots = afterDots.Substring(1, afterDots.Length - 1);

if(beforeDots.Length > 0)
   beforeDots = beforeDots.Substring(1, beforeDots.Length - 1);
```

Is there any better way to solve this either by linq or by some easier logic?

Comment: Shouldn't your `beforeDots` be `1,3,5,7,9` ?

Comment: correct, changes made

Answer (score 0):

You could clean your logic up a little bit:

```
string input = "1.2 3.4 5.6 7.8 9";

List<string> beforeDot = new List<string>();
List<string> afterDot = new List<string>();

foreach(string s in input.Split())
{
    var split = s.Split('.');

    beforeDot.Add(split[0]);

    if(split.Length == 2)
    {               
        afterDot.Add(split[1]);
    }
}

string beforeDots = string.Join(", ", beforeDot);
string afterDots = string.Join(", ", afterDot);
```

This gives you the added benefit of having the numbers preserved individually (beforeDot, afterDot) if you need to use it for other logic.

**There really isn't any need to use LINQ here.**

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IcU8ra)

Comment: The value`9` is missing from `beforeDots`

Comment: @Xiaoy312 good call, I thought for some reason the OP wanted to omit the single numbers (i.e numbers with no dots).  I was mistaken.  I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest splitting the string, and then using linq.

Edit: I missed the space between number before, the updated method below will work with the spaces taken into account.

```
string input = "1.2 3.4 5.6 7.8 9";
//split, assign index, flatten, group by index.
var inputGroups = input.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Split('.')).Select(x=>x.Select((number, i)=>new { Number = number, Index = i })).SelectMany(x=>x).GroupBy(x=>x.Index);
//group with index 0 was before the dot
var beforeDot= inputGroups.Where(grp=>grp.Key == 0) .FirstOrDefault().Select(x=>x.Number);
//group with key 1 was after the dot
var afterDot= inputGroups.Where(x=>x.Key == 1).FirstOrDefault().Select(x => x.Number);

//then use string.Join(",", str);
var commaSeparatedBefore = string.Join(",",beforeDot);
var commaSeparatedAfter = string.Join(",", afterDot);
```

Comment: I think you miss the spaces in input `1.2            3.4           5.6            7.8            9`

Comment: oh, true, I did.

Comment: edited my answer, it works with the spaces taken into account now.

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize this for any `T` with extremely simple and mantainable code without using linq:

```
public static (IEnumerable<T> Prefixes, IEnumerable<T> suffixes)
    Separate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T splitOn, T resetOn)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    var isSuffix = false;
    var prefixes = new List<T>();
    var suffixes = new List<T>();

    foreach (var c in source)
    {
        if (c.Equals(splitOn))
        {
            isSuffix = true;
        }
        else if (c.Equals(resetOn))
        {
            isSuffix = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (isSuffix)
            {
                suffixes.Add(c);
            }
            else
            {
                prefixes.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }

    return (prefixes, suffixes);
}
```

And usage is rather straightforward:

```
var res = "1.2 3.4 5.6 7.8 9".Separate('.', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is strings (which can be parsed after the fact):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "1.2 3.4 5.6 7.8 9";

        var pairs = input.Split(' ').Select(
            s =>
            {
                var split = s.Split('.');

                return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(split[0],split.Length > 1 ? split[1] : null);
            });

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", pairs.Select(p => p.Key)));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", pairs.Where(p=>p.Value != null).Select(p => p.Value)));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You, guys, are overcomplicating this. All in all, these are just decimal numbers. So I'll do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = "1.2 3.4 5.6 7.8 9";
    var numbers = input.Split().Select(s => decimal.Parse(s));

    var beforeDots = numbers.Select(n => (int)Math.Truncate(n));
    var afterDots = numbers.Select(n => (int)((n - Math.Truncate(n)) * 10));

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", beforeDots));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", afterDots));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

// Output:
// 1,3,5,7,9
// 2,4,6,8,0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
var tmp = input.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Split('.'));
var beforeDots = string.Join(",", tmp.Select(x => x.First()));
var afterDots = string.Join(",", tmp.Select(x => x.ElementAtOrDefault(1)).Where(x => x != null));
```

Comment: @maverick What do you mean it is not working? Check the result: https://dotnetfiddle.net/asBPyy

Comment: You need to import `System.Linq`